# Backbone.js focus event fires two events focus and focusin

Tags: focus, backbone.js, dom-events, focusin

The view part of my code using Backbone.js is something like this:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'focus .cell input'     : "updateCurrentCell"
    },
    updateCurrentCell: function(event) {
        console.log('updateCurrentCell called');
        // Update the current cell.
    }
}
```

Whenever the input element gets focus, the function is called twice. I tried printing the stack trace using `console.trace()`. It shows that once the function call originated from **focus** event while the next time from **focusin**.

My attempts to find out how to prevent one of these events getting fired lead me nowhere.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Backbone.View uses [delegateEvents](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) to bind the events listed in your events object. If you take a look at the [source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html), you'll see that `delegateEvents` uses [jQuery.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to do so.

There's a note in the jquery docs for [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus) that's probably relevant:

> The focus event does not bubble in Internet Explorer. Therefore,
>   scripts that rely on     event delegation with the focus event will
>   not work consistently across browsers. As of version 1.4.2, however,
>   jQuery **works around this limitation by mapping focus to the focusin**
>   event in its event delegation methods, .live() and **.delegate()**.

In theory, this should just work fine, but since you're getting both, perhaps you could try to  just listen for the [.focusin()](http://api.jquery.com/focusin) event, as it supports the kind of event bubbling [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) listens for and is what jQuery is trying to map 'focus' to anyway.

Comment: Ya I have seen the jQuery doc for `focus()`. I doubted it could be an issue in Backbone, not jquery.

Is focusin a standard event, supported by all browsers?

Comment: I did a quick search, and couldn't find anything to suggest that it isn't. More importantly, jQuery's purpose is cross-browser support, and if it's mapping focus to focusin, I don't see any reason not to use it.

Comment: focusin is not supported in firefox see: